# Raspberry Pi, qt creator GUI executable issue

Tags: raspberry-pi, qt-creator, raspbian

Created a GUI on Raspbian with qtcreator. Program runs in qt creator but executable does not run (i.e. trying to run it out of qt). Interestingly the same executable runs on a different Raspberry Pi.

Both Pi's have qt creator installed, same versions, etc. When you click run in qt creator the program appears to run fine. I will note that the second Pi (the one with the issue) is the Pi 2 and the original one is the previous model.

Interestingly the Size on disk of the first one is around 1.4mb and the total size of files is 175.2kb. However the second is 175.2kb for both.

Comment: Does the other Raspberry have Qt or an app which uses Qt installed? I'm not a raspbian expert, but your issue looks like a missing libraries one, which often arises when deploying. Which steps did you you follow?

Comment: "Program runs in qt" - you probably mean "in Qt Creator"? And isn't there output on the console when you run it?